# i am working on my coursework and i dont know how to do a format check on it

Tags: python, python-3.x, checkbox, format

i am working on my coursework at the moment and I am finding it hard to do a format check on the number plates.
this is my code so far

```
f = open("JAMES1.TXT","r")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    numberplates = line[0:7]   
    start_time = int(line[9:13])
    end_time = int(line[14:18])
    time = (end_time - start_time)
    time2= (time/60)
    distance_camera = int(40)
    speed = distance_camera/time2
    if speed > 30: 
        print("these number plates have been execeding the speed limit",numberplates,speed,"mph")        
f.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "format check"?

Comment: What format should they have?

Comment: If you're expecting the lines in `JAMES1.TXT` to be a particular format, you'll likely want to use the re module to use a regular expression to check the format of each line. You can also use it to extract all of those pieces of information, as an added bonus.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with regular expressions. Without knowing what format you expect, or how you want to handle an invalid plate, you could do something like this:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{3}')
if not pattern.match(number_plate):
    exception = ValueError('Invalid plate number {0}'.format(number_plate))
    raise exception
```

I've assumed that your format is three digits, followed by three letters. And that you want to throw an error if you encounter an badly formatted plate.